# Colorbox - Can't maintain multiple groups without errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I am using Colorbox [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/walkthroughs.html).

If you look at the setup, I have multiple groups on one page. I have identified their groups as groups 1 thru 9, respectively. But when I click on the second and third items, it displays the way it should based on the author's code. I want everything to display the same way Group1 is identified (which is an Elastic Transition). But, if I lump everything under Group1, then they'll all be part of the same image gallery, and I don't want that.

```
<h2>OAC Walkthrough</h2> <!--Elastic Transition-->
<p><a class="group1" href="content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="OAC Welcome Page">OAC Welcome Page</a></p>
<p><a class="group1 hidden" href="content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="OAC Page 2">OAC Page 2</a></p>
<p><a class="group1 hidden" href="content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="OAC Page 3">OAC Page 3</a></p>


<h2>FAFSA Walkthrough</h2> <!--Elastic Transition-->
<p><a class="group2" href="content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="FAFSA Welcome Page">FAFSA Welcome Page</a></p>
<p><a class="group2 hidden" href="content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="FAFSA Page 2">FAFSA Page 2</a></p>
<p><a class="group2 hidden" href="content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="FAFSA Page 3">FAFSA Page 3</a></p>

<h2>FAFSA PIN Walkthrough</h2> <!--Elastic Transition-->
<p><a class="group3" href="content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="PIN Welcome Page">PIN Welcome Page</a></p>
<p><a class="group3 hidden" href="content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="PIN Page 2">PIN Page 2</a></p>
<p><a class="group3 hidden" href="content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="PIN Page 3">PIN Page 3</a></p>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Wow! I'm surprised nobody's helping out with this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there is the following code in the  tags of the code...

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
$(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
$(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
$(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
```

I simply removed the groups 2, 3, and 4, and took the nomenclature of Group 1 and repeated it to look like this...

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
$(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2'});
$(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3'});
$(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4'});
$(".group5").colorbox({rel:'group5'});
$(".group6").colorbox({rel:'group6'});
$(".group7").colorbox({rel:'group7'});
$(".group8").colorbox({rel:'group8'});
$(".group9").colorbox({rel:'group9'});
```

...because I have a total of 9 groups. Everything's good now.